# Formulario wordpress

Tags: wordpress, formularios

El titulo es muy poco informativo, pero espero que con esta descripción de mi problema sea claro:

Quisiera saber si hay algun plugin (gratis o de pago) que realice lo siguiente: Un formulario donde solo se muestre un campo (CODIGO) y dependiendo de ese código se abra un formulario (diferente para cada codigo).

Actualmente busque información para Ninja form y Contact form 7 pero no he solucionado mi duda.

De antemano gracias por leer y espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

Comment: Hola @Erick. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Si bien puede ser interesante, la pregunta busca respuestas basadas en opiniones. Esto es algo que se intenta evitar en el sitio. La idea es realizar preguntas que tengan una respuesta única válida, que no dependa de lo que un solo desarrollador haya realizado o prefiera. ¿Crees que podrías orientarla sobre algo que hayas intentado y tengas dudas específicas? Quizás te sea útil leer [ask], para llevarla a lo descripto en [mcve]. La alternativa es preguntar en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).